# Start and stop face tracking

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I'm making a filter that counts the number of times you blink in x number of seconds.

After the x seconds are up I want it to stop counting the blinks, but I can't seem to drag any other patch to the face finder/tracking/select/blink patches.

The logic I've managed to create so far is:

1. Display text which says "Don't blink"
2. When the user starts recording, this text disappears and another text which says "start blinking" appears
3. When the user blinks this other text disappears and a 1 appears, then a 2, and a 3 and so on
4. After 5 seconds since the user started recording a new text appears, "Finished!"
5. I know want the blinking counting to stop

Here's what I have to far:
[image]

Comment: Do you know that counter have 5 counts maximum?

Comment: I've extended the counter up to 8 now and it works fine